# Destroying a Doubly Linked List in C

Tags: c, visual-studio, doubly-linked-list

The purpose of this function in the code below, which passes in a doubly linked list, is to take the nodes in the list one by one and free() them. But every time I try to debug my program. It gives me this message: "Exception thrown: read access violation. currNode was nullptr." I am having trouble making sense of this in my code, what am I doing wrong or am missing that is causing this?

```
void DListDestruct(DList* list) {
DListNode* currNode;
DListNode* next;

currNode = (DListNode*)malloc(sizeof(DListNode));
currNode = list->head;

if (currNode == NULL) {
    return;
}


while (list->head != NULL) {

    next = currNode->next;
    free(currNode);
    currNode = (DListNode*)malloc(sizeof(DListNode));
    currNode = next;

}

list->head = NULL;

return;
}
```

Comment: `malloc` is not required. and `while (list->head != NULL) {` --> `while (currNode != NULL) {`

Comment: Your consecutive lines `currNode = (DListNode*)malloc(sizeof(DListNode));` and 
`currNode = list->head;` leak memory.  Don't allocate and then overwrite the pointer that points to the allocated space.

Comment: "*... currNode was nullptr.*" sounds like C++.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is testing `list->head`, which the body of the loop never changes.  Since `currNode` is what gets freed, that is probably what you should be checking.